# Angular: Do validators remove and re-assign errors on value changes (when they run)?

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have created the below custom group validator which checks if passwords match. It works great however there is something I do not know WHY IT WORKS.

```
export class CustomGroupValidators {
   static matchFields(field1: string, field2: string, errorKey: string): ValidatorFn {
      return (group: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
         const firstField = group.get(field1);
         const secondField = group.get(field2);

         if (firstField?.value !== secondField?.value) {
            secondField?.setErrors({ mismatch: true });
            return { [errorKey]: true };
         } else {
            return null;
         }
      };
   };
}
```

- The validator also sets an error to the second field if the matchFields validator itself returns error so I can provide feedback to the user.

As you can see I do not clear or reset any errors, however when first & second fields match validation works right and second field is valid - as per my wish. Does this mean that whenever a validator runs (either on a field or a group), it clears all the errors and re-evaluates / re-attaches those needed? Otherwise why don't I encounter a bug where "mismatch" error is still true when prior value caused the error to be set but current value is good?

Also I do not clearly understand under which events validators run in general. I know they run on value changes however are there any other circumstances under which they run in addition to that?

Comment: Be careful!, only put the errors to null if the input you're editing is the "second field" (each time you type the input make the check), but if you change the "first field" the error remains although the two fields match

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for your response. Since I am fairly new to Angular, how would you suggest I do what you mentioned? Actually I do not get it, why is my code not completely ok since the validator "matchFields" runs every time a value in the form group changes? The validator is assigned to the form group and not the field2 control.

Comment: Each change in any field of the formGroup, Angular execute the validator of the field you're changing and, after, execute the CustomGroupValidators. But If you change the "first field", Angular change only the "second field" if not match. You need add a condition to change the status of the "second field" if match (It's only add a setValidators(null) in this case -well, first check if has value to not delete the Validators.required-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the validators assigned to an `AbstractControl` are re-run each time value of the control changes AND the control is enabled.

Note that the changes traverse up the tree, so changing a `FormControl` inside a `FormGroup` will change the value of both the control and the group - with `FormControl` taking precedence.

[This](http://(this%20as%20%7Berrors:%20ValidationErrors%20%7C%20null%7D).errors%20=%20this._runValidator();) is a part of code responsible for running validators when value changes.

So in your case, angular will first run validators on your `secondField`. In case of no validators (or validators returning null), errors array is empty and status is set to VALID.

Then, the same happens for your `FormGroup` - errors on the group are cleared, and your validators are run.

Comment: Thank you very much @TotallyNewb, your answer is really helpful. I couldn't find the answer on Google and for me it is important to understand how things work - just having the code working is not enough if I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

complementary my comment, the "customGroupValidators need use `setErrors(null)` when the fields match. As I suppose the two fields has Validators.required, only set to null when has value

```
export class CustomGroupValidators {
   static matchFields(field1: string, field2: string, errorKey: string): ValidatorFn {
      return (group: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
         const firstField = group.get(field1);
         const secondField = group.get(field2);

         if (firstField?.value !== secondField?.value) {
            secondField?.setErrors({ mismatch: true });
            return { [errorKey]: true };
         } else {
            
            if (secondField?.value) //<--if match and secondField has value
                secondField?.setErrors(null); //<--setErrors to null

            return null;
         }
      };
   };
}
```

Imagine that we edit the "second field". Angular check the "second field", give errors according is valid or not and execute the FormGroup Validator to validate the FormGroup (who change the errors if not match)

Imagine that we edit the "first field". Angular check the "first field", give errors to this according is valid or not and execute the FromGroup validator to validate the formGroup which use setErrors({[errorKey]} is not match and setErrors(null) if match and the second field has value.

Comment: I still do not get it. Let me describe in detail: The first field has 2 validators: required and min length of 8 chars. The second field has 1 validator: required. The second field is disabled until the first field is valid. If I type "12345678" in the first field, then type "12345677" in the second field and then correct the first field to "12345678", validator still works. I really cannot get my head around the problem your are addressing.

Comment: In addition, as @TotallyNewb said in his answer, the error keys are cleared and re-assigned if needed after every value change in the fields belonging to the group so where is the issue here? The fact that I do not set errors to null in success case but do not get any bugs is the reason I posts my question in the first place.